# Why do we often see 2 blocks mined within a few seconds of each other?

Tags: mining-theory, block-interval

This seems to happen far more frequently than one would expect from a Poisson distribution with a ~10 minute mean. Am I just bad at statistics or is something else going on?

Comment: Upvoted, it'd be interesting to see the probability of, for example the next block being made in under a minute. (I think that has the probability of 0.095 according to [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0.1e%5E%28-0.1*t%29+from+t+%3D+0+to+t%3D+1), with the help of [RC](http://r6.ca/blog/20180225T160548Z.html)'s blog though I'm not knowledgeable enough to write an answer.)

Comment: Is your "this seems" based on calculations, or just a guess?  If calculations, would you like to share them?

Comment: I haven't done any calculations, just a guess from something I noticed. Would be interesting if anyone felt inclined to put together some actual numbers

Comment: I can produce some statistics based on the block timestamps if it would be of interest, but given that they do not necessarily correspond to the time at which the blocks were mined or broadcast, I don't know if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> is something else going on?

Maybe.

AFAIK Mining nodes don't synchronize time. Timestamps in blocks are not accurate. You cannot tell the elapsed time between two blocks by looking at timestamps in those blocks.

Answer (score -2):

this may happened when the two consecutive blocks belongs to the same miner and the second block is normally empty. 
460564 AntPool 0 minutes

460533 AntPool 4 minutes

460501 BTC.TOP 6 minutes (460502 BTCC full block right after)

460445 AntPool 1 minutes

460432 F2Pool 0 minutes

460308 GoGreenLight 3 minutes

460281 AntPool 3 minutes

460238 AntPool 1 minutes

460218 1Hash 10 minutes

459932 AntPool 1 minutes

https://criptomonedaseico.com/en/news-en/proof-of-nothing-why-bitcoin-miner-propagate-empty-blocks/